# Why am I not hitting some breakpoints in my managed C++ DLL (even though they are solid red at debug-time)?

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, c++-cli, breakpoints

I have made a DLL which contains a managed C++ class that wraps some of the functionality of a C library. I have a C# test project which references the managed C++ DLL.  Unmanaged debugging is turned on in the C# project, and I have set Debugger Type=Mixed in the C++ DLL project.  Here's a sort of diagram of what I've got:

*C# console app -> wrapper DLL -> managed C++ class -> unmanaged C++ methods (implemented in wrapper DLL) -> C static lib*

I have breakpoints set in both the managed wrapper class, and in the unmanaged methods in the DLL.  When I start debugging, all of my breakpoints remain solid red.  The breakpoints in the managed wrapper class are hit, but the ones in the unmanaged methods are not.  Strangely, when I try to step into any of the unmanaged methods, the debugger "skips over" the unmanaged C++ methods and goes straight into functions in the C static lib.  At that point, the call stack shows [External Code] where I would expect it to show my unmanaged C++ method.

Any ideas about what might be happening here?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? (e.g. 2008, 2010,...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're loading the dll from the right location? You can check this through the Modules view.

Comment: In modules view for the managed C++ dll, it's showing the path to the bin\debug folder of the C# test app.  I am referencing it from the bin\debug folder of the dll project.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the EXE then going to Debug | Attach to Process in VS.

Select the EXE and make sure that

"Managed" and "Native" are selected in "Attach to:"

That is what I have used before and seems to work ok...

Answer (score 0):

In my case (VS2015_SP1) I have to use Debugger-Option:
Debug->Options->General->Use native Compatibility Mode